# How can I create Azure alerts with webhook to a Teams channel using Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, devops

I have a template that is called from several repositories with which, using Terraform, I create alerts for metrics, budgets and more. I would like these metrics to be configured to send alerts to a Teams channel.

I already have the action group modules, budget alerts and others.

For now, try placing the URL of the incomming Webhook of the teams channel in the action group:

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_action_group" "ag" {
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name

  name       = var.action_group_name
  short_name = var.short_name

  dynamic "email_receiver" {
    for_each = var.email_address == "" ? toset([]) : toset([1])
    content {
      name                    = var.email_name
      email_address           = var.email_address
      use_common_alert_schema = var.use_common_alert_schema
    }
  }

  dynamic "webhook_receiver" {
    for_each = var.webhook_service_uri == "" ? toset([]) : toset([1])
    content {
      name                    = var.webhook_name
      **service_uri             = var.webhook_service_uri**
      use_common_alert_schema = var.use_common_alert_schema
    }
  }

  tags = {}

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      tags["DPCCODE"],
      tags["EAICODE"],
      tags["ENV"],
      tags["TENANT"]
    ]
  }
}
```

But this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to create Azure alerts with webhook to a Teams channel using Terraform and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

If placing the URL of the incoming webhook of the Teams channel in the action group did not work as expected, there could be several reasons behind this issue.

**Incorrect Webhook URL**: The most common issue is an incorrect or malformed webhook URL. Double-check that the webhook URL copied from Teams is complete and correctly entered in your Terraform configuration.

**Webhook URL Not Supported by Azure Action Group**: Ensure that the webhook URL provided by Microsoft Teams is supported by Azure Monitor and Action Groups. Azure expects certain formats and protocols for webhook URLs, and if the Teams webhook doesn't comply, it may not trigger as expected.

**Common Alert Schema**: If `use_common_alert_schema` is set incorrectly, it might affect how alerts are sent. The Common Alert Schema standardizes the format of the alert, and some services, including certain configurations of Teams webhooks, may require this schema to parse the alert correctly. Ensure this setting aligns with your requirements.

**Teams Channel Configuration**: The Teams channel itself may have configurations or restrictions that prevent it from receiving messages from external sources. Verify the Teams channel settings to ensure it's set up to accept incoming webhooks

I tried the same configuration using new webhook created  from the teams and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

[image]

**My terraform configuration:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = var.resource_group_name
  location = var.location
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_action_group" "ag" {
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  name                = var.action_group_name
  short_name          = var.short_name

  dynamic "email_receiver" {
    for_each = var.email_address == "" ? toset([]) : toset([1])
    content {
      name                    = var.email_name
      email_address           = var.email_address
      use_common_alert_schema = var.use_common_alert_schema
    }
  }

  dynamic "webhook_receiver" {
    for_each = var.webhook_service_uri == "" ? toset([]) : toset([1])
    content {
      name                    = var.webhook_name
      service_uri             = var.webhook_service_uri
      use_common_alert_schema = var.use_common_alert_schema
    }
  }
}

# Example Metric Alert for a VM's CPU usage
resource "azurerm_monitor_metric_alert" "vm_cpu_usage" {
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  name                = "vm-cpu-usage-alert"
  scopes              = [var.vm_id]
  description         = "Alert when CPU usage is over 75%"

  criteria {
    metric_namespace = "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
    metric_name      = "Percentage CPU"
    aggregation      = "Average"
    operator         = "GreaterThan"
    threshold        = 75

  }

}

# Example Budget Alert
resource "azurerm_consumption_budget_resource_group" "budget" {
  name                 = "demovk-budget"
  resource_group_id  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.id
  amount               = 1000
  
  time_grain           = "Monthly"
  
  time_period {
    start_date = "2024-02-01T00:00:00Z"
  }
  notification {
    enabled   = true
    operator  = "GreaterThan"
    threshold = 90
    contact_emails = [
      var.email_address
    ]
    contact_groups = [
      azurerm_monitor_action_group.ag.id
    ]
  }
}
```

**variable.tf:**

```
variable "resource_group_name" {
  description = "The name of the resource group."
  type        = string
}

variable "location" {
  description = "The Azure region where the resource group should be created."
  type        = string
}

variable "action_group_name" {
  description = "The name of the action group."
  type        = string
}

variable "short_name" {
  description = "The short name of the action group."
  type        = string
}

variable "email_address" {
  description = "The email address to send alerts to."
  type        = string
  default     = ""
}

variable "email_name" {
  description = "The name of the email receiver."
  type        = string
  default     = "defaultEmail"
}

variable "webhook_service_uri" {
  description = "The service URI for the webhook receiver."
  type        = string
  default     = ""
}

variable "webhook_name" {
  description = "The name of the webhook receiver."
  type        = string
  default     = "defaultWebhook"
}

variable "use_common_alert_schema" {
  description = "Whether to use the common alert schema."
  type        = bool
  default     = true
}

variable "vm_id" {
  description = "The ID of the VM for monitoring CPU usage."
  type        = string
}
```

**terraform.tfvars:**

```
resource_group_name       = "example-rg"
location                  = "East US"
action_group_name         = "example-action-group"
short_name                = "exAG"
email_address             = "alert@example.com"
email_name                = "Example Email Alert"
webhook_service_uri       = "https://outlook.office.com/webhook/your-teams-channel-webhook-url"
webhook_name              = "Teams Webhook"
use_common_alert_schema   = true
vm_id                     = "/subscriptions/your-subscription-id/resourceGroups/example-rg/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/example-vm"
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]